# MVC 3 Validation for confirm email address field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate, custom-attributes

Is there a way using MVC data validation attributes to validate client side if two fields on my model are equal.

I have two fields:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to add an attribute that those two fields should be equel and if not an validatio error will appear. Is there a way to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: Create a new project (one that includes the default login/register stuff)  Then take a look at the Registration model.  It compares the passwords.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yep - for example:

```
[Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "The email and confirmation do not match.")]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at the [`CompareAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

```
[Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "The email and confirmation email do not match.")]
public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Adam Tuliper - actually what's odd is that I answered slightly before Russ (2 seconds originally), then he added my answer to his (note the  same 'ErrorMessage'), yet in the end mine got accepted. So indeed, it is funny how it works!